# problem in recognizing duplicated code in the line bellow

Tags: java, refactoring

I have trouble finding which part of the code is duplicated and how to fix it ?

```
try {
    String template = new String(sourceTemplate);
    // Substitute for %CODE%
    int templateSplitBegin = template.indexOf("%CODE%");
    int templateSplitEnd = templateSplitBegin + 6;
    String templatePartOne = new String(
        template.substring(0, templateSplitBegin));
    String templatePartTwo = new String(
        template.substring(templateSplitEnd, template.length()));
    code = new String(reqId);
    template = new String(templatePartOne + code + templatePartTwo);
    // Substitute for %ALTCODE%
    templateSplitBegin = template.indexOf("%ALTCODE%");
    templateSplitEnd = templateSplitBegin + 9;
    templatePartOne = new String(
        template.substring(0, templateSplitBegin));
    templatePartTwo = new String(
        template.substring(templateSplitEnd, template.length()));
    altcode = code.substring(0, 5) + "-" + code.substring(5, 8);
    out.print(templatePartOne + altcode + templatePartTwo);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error in substitute()");
}
```

Comment: Basically half of it is the same code with different parameters, which means it can be extracted to a method.

Comment: There is no good reason to be using `new String (str)` here. Get rid of them, just use `str` directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

this two parts are duplicated. you can make a method to process the string

```
try {
     String template = new String(sourceTemplate);
           // Substitute for %CODE%
           code = new String(reqId);
           template = processString(template, 6, "%CODE%", code);
           // Substitute for %ALTCODE%
           altcode = code.substring(0, 5) + "-" + code.substring(5, 8);
           template = processString(template, 9, "%ALTCODE%", altcode);
           out.print(template);
       } catch (Exception e) {

       }

 private String processString(String template, int length, String code, String mid) {
       int templateSplitBegin = template.indexOf(code);
       int templateSplitEnd = templateSplitBegin + len;
       String templatePartOne = new String(
               template.substring(0, templateSplitBegin));
       String templatePartTwo = new String(
               template.substring(templateSplitEnd, template.length()));
       return new String(templatePartOne + mid + templatePartTwo);
   }
```

Comment: Please put your code in your answer as text and not an image link. I will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a method with `(String template, String splitBy, int offset)` as parameters.

also, you can try using `stringBegin = template.split(splitBy)[0]` and `stringEnd = template.split(splitBy)[1]` instead of using `indexOf()` and then `substring()`